# Period after Hi (Hi.)

Tags: punctuation, grammaticality-in-context, greetings

We usually write:

> **Hi, John.**

But if I'd like to write simply **Hi** followed by a Period, ie,

> **Hi.**
>
> **How are you?**

Is it correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"The reader's ability to comprehend the logic included within their written expression and the reader's ability to read the writing aloud with proper vocal inflections and cadence is what is important" as said by [whackademic](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/257266/328744).
Both your sentence can be used if the punctuation helps a person in understanding what was inferred to him/her.

[Hi](http://www.manythings.org/sentences/words/hi/1.html) used in different types of sentences,

- Hi! How are you?
- Hi, how're you doing?
- Hi. How are you?
- Hi, Fred, how about badminton on Thursday?
- Hi. If I'm not mistaken, you're our new neighbors, aren't you?

You might also want to take a look at [Hello](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51676/is-hello-a-sentence) which is similar to your question and also all the answers there can be applicable to 'Hi' also.